# React js. When i clicked to button to change background-color in doc.body, color was changed. But when i tried to change color of section, it didn't

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I'm trying to learn React js. I wrote the function, that should change the color of section, but it didn't do this. But when i save the jsx document where function located, everything start working. But when i refresh the page problem is back. Console gave me this - cannot read properties of null. Seems like a func cant see variable.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18Q1O.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zEHM.png)

```
import './Pick_color.module.scss'

const Pick_color = () =>{

let color = document.querySelector('#color');
let colorSpan = document.querySelector('.color_span');
let btnColor = document.querySelector('#color_btn');
let Hex = ["a","b","c","d",'e',"f",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];

const handleClick =()=>{
    
    let finalHex = []
    for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        finalHex.push(Hex[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)])
    }
    // document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#" + finalHex.join('');
    color.style.backgroundColor = "#" + finalHex.join('');
    colorSpan.innerHTML = ("#" + finalHex.join('')).toUpperCase();
}

return (
    <>
    <section  id="color">
        <h1 className="color_title">Background Color:
            <span className="color_span">#F1F5F8</span>
        </h1>
        <button onClick={handleClick} id="color_btn">Click Me</button>
        <a href="#"><h3>Main Color</h3></a>
    </section>
    </>
)

}



export default Pick_color
```

I tried to change scss, tried to change of color of doc.body it's work.

Comment: Directly interacting with the DOM is almost always the wrong approach in React.  In whatever tutorial(s) you're following, you've missed the central fundamental part of React... *state*.  One or more state values should determine how the component is rendered.  The JSX would use those state values to conditionally render one thing or another, and the click handler would update those state values.

Comment: Ok thanks. I dont use tutors, just doing. So my guessing was true, problem with DOM. So  I'm gonna go and continue to learn about states.